# CSS3 not working on HTML

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm building my first website using bootstrap and the CSS is not working on any of the html.  What am I doing wrong here?  I am very new to web design and bootstrap and understand I have to link the HTML to the Bootstrap server to be able to use the feature, but am I doing it right here?

How long does it take to learn Bootstrap and is there a better way to go instead of constantly writing `div`s all day long?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Ignite Studio Portfolio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">     </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed-nav-bar" id="nav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="#">Ignite Studio Portfolio</a>       
              <a href="#" >Home</a>
              <a href="#">Web</a>   
              <a href="#">Programming</a>
              <a href="#">Art</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS3 code:

```
body {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
};

.container-fluid {
  background-color: pink;
};

.fixed-nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
};

#navhead {
  font-color: orange;
};
```

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: Is <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css"> the css posted above? Bootstrap wants custom.css and you put that in a folder called css. Your link would now look <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">  You post that line right below the bootstrap.css line

Comment: He is linking to the Bootstrap CDN for the Bootstrap CSS, in addition to linking to a custom CSS file. It doesn't matter what his additional CSS file is called, or where it is stored.

Comment: Yes ...I got half of it working but the navhead ID is not changing my text to orange.  Is the call to bootstrap ok?  Did I do something wrong there maybe?

Comment: That's because it's not `font-color` , but just `color`

Comment: I want to make a horizontal navigation bar with the name of the website on the far left as a link and the 3 categories as far right buttons/links.  I want the nav-bar to be fixed so I can scroll through the content underneath it.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools, F12 in most browsers, to investigate further. Check the external links aren't returning 404 errors. Then investigate the fixed nav bar elements and see if more specific selectors are overriding your selector.

Comment: In your html supplied, there is no element with an id of `navhead`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove semi-colon after closing flower bracket in css. it should work!

> if you don't want to write code than use bootstrap builder tool.. A
>   powerful desktop app for creating responsive websites using the
>   Bootstrap framework.

```
https://bootstrapstudio.io/
```

Comment: nope you're wrong.. check this out..https://jsfiddle.net/klakshman318/pbqcoksc/1/ remove semi colons and let me know the difference.

Comment: get it? @ObsidianAge

Comment: Removing the semi-colons definitely did something to fix it up.  Is the bootstrap builder easier to use and is it free?

Comment: nope, it's a premium tool.. do some research you might find some better tools with free trial option. :)

Answer (score 0):

The text color property is called `color`, not `font-color` (last rule)

Also, remove all the semicolons after the closing brackets of the CSS rules, and check the filepath to your CSS file.